# Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found, installation error in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I installed Laravel without using composer with typing this command:

> C:\wamp\www\travail>laravel new project

It seems that it is on the good way.

> Creating application...
>
> Application ready! Build something amazing.

But when I tried to open my project here:

> wamp-->localhost-->travail-->project-->public

I got this error:

> Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solve this issue by doing the following:

1. Check the `minimum-stability` value in composer.json and set it to *stable*:

   ```
   "minimum-stability": "stable"
   ```
2. Update you composer:

   ```
   composer self-update
   ```
3. Re-run composer udpate:

   ```
   composer update
   ```

Then run any artisan commands and enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://laravel.io/forum/02-18-2014-class-monologlogger-not-found). Change `minimum-stability` from `dev` to `stable` in `composer.json`, then run an update. Also try to do a `dump-autoload`.

Comment: thanks but in my composer.json file  minimum-stability is "stable"  and when i try to update with composer update or i try to type composer dump-autoload it dosen't work an error seems like  composer could not find the config file c:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin to initialize a  project ,please create a composer.json file as described in http://getcomposer.org getting started section

Comment: here is my composer.json file 
{
 "name": "laravel/laravel",
 "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
 "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
 "license": "MIT",
 "require": {
  "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
 },

Comment: "autoload": {
  "classmap": [
   "app/commands",
   "app/controllers",
   "app/models",
   "app/database/migrations",
   "app/database/seeds",
   "app/tests/TestCase.php"
  ]
 },
 "scripts": {
  "post-install-cmd": [
   "php artisan clear-compiled",
   "php artisan optimize"
  ],
  "post-update-cmd": [
   "php artisan clear-compiled",
   "php artisan optimize"
  ],
  "post-create-project-cmd": [
   "php artisan key:generate"
  ]
 },
 "config": {
  "preferred-install": "dist"
 },
 "minimum-stability": "stable"
}

Comment: and this here is the error page Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found
open: C:\wamp\www\travail\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider.php
  * Register the service provider.
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function register()
 {
  $logger = new Writer(
   new Logger($this->app['env']), $this->app['events']
  );

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works for me after running these two commands:

> composer self-update

Then:

> composer update --no-scripts

Comment: But also don't forget to change the "dev" to "stable"