# Laravel Setup: Can't install Monolog

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I just tried to install a fresh instance of Laravel as described in the docs ( http://laravel.com/docs/quick#installation - "Via Composer"). Got this error from Composer:

```
...
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found in ...\src\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider.php on line 23
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Monolog\\Logger' not found","file":"...\\src\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Log\\LogServiceProvider.php","line":23}}Script php artisan clear-c
ompiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found in ...\src\Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider.php on line 23

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found in ...\src\Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider.php on line 23
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Monolog\\Logger' not found","file":"...\\src\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Log\\LogServiceProvider.php","line":23}}Script php artisan optimiz
e handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found in ...\src\Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider.php on line 23
```

Uhm, what to do now? Tried to post it on the official forums but that wasn't possible due to an error there (forums are based on Laravel... yeah that's Karma!).

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748276/class-monolog-logger-not-found-installation-error-in-laravel-4

Comment: And this? http://laravel.io/forum/02-18-2014-class-monologlogger-not-found

Comment: Thanks, your second link was helpful!

Comment: Cheers. If you managed to fix it don't forget to add as an answer too!

Comment: Ah I was a few minutes behind. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: "composer dumpautoload -o"